# Auto Attach process in Visual Basic

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, process

I'm trying to make a plugin where, once clicked, it will automatically attach a certain process. I was just wondering, how would I go about this?

I have a list of the processes currently running, so now I have to go through the list and select only the one element.

The element has to be called for example, "Process190", and the Username has to contain "Administrator".

How would I go about finding this process and then attaching it?

Thanks for any help

***EDIT***

Okay I figured out how to get the list of processes and sort them and get the process I need.
So now I have a process, I just need to know how can I attach the process? 
I want it so that if I go to Tools/Attach Process, and scroll to the process, I can see it greyed out as it's in use.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 3):

[Here](http://blog.lavablast.com/post/2008/01/11/Attach-to-Process-with-one-shortcut.aspx) is a explanation to create a macro in Visual Studio (its in VB.NET though) and attach the process using a shortcut.

You could also look into Extensions (menu 'Extensions and Updates') and search for 'Attach'.

---Edit---

Or create your own extensions, see [Walkthrough: Creating a Menu Command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb164725%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: I didn't downvote you just to let you know.
I have to make it as a plugin for somebody, they want an icon in the tool bar that will toggle the process being attached and not being attached.

Comment: If you really need to make an Extension for Visual Studio look here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/vextend.aspx. I've made extensions in the past (designers) and it's not simple.

Comment: I already have the process that I want to do. I got all the processes that equal w3wp and then filtered them by there User Name to just get Administrators.

All I need to do now is find out how to attach it. Which I don't know how to do